# После установки и запуска Apache Tomcat не могу открыть localhost:8080, требует авторизацию

Tags: apache, веб-программирование, tomcat

Установил Apache TomCat 8.0, запустил startup.bat, получил сообщение, что сервер успешно запустился,  открываю в браузере `localhost:8080`, по идее должна открыться их (Apache TomCat) страница, но вместо этого появляется окно с требованием аутефикации `«http://localhost:8080» запрашивает имя пользователя и пароль. Сайт сообщает: «XDB»` Что делать?

Comment: @will_hunting, это уже другой вопрос. пожалуйста, задайте его с помощью кнопки [задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: @Sapphiron, оформите, пожалуйста, ваш комментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй ввести логин/пароль из файла tomcat-user.xml в папке conf. Если их там нет, то добавь сам. Выглядит это примерно так

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/> 
<role rolename="role1"/> 
<role rolename="manager-gui"/> 
<user username="username" password="superSecretPassword" roles="tomcat, manager-gui"/>
```